# PyQGIS QgsProcessingAlgorithm: no output layer when cancelled

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

For one plugin I maintain, I can't figure out how to return output layer when the user hits 'Cancel'. Basically I'm looping over a set of results in `processAlgorithm` which populates the output layer and I'd expect to have the output layer returned with all results calculated until 'Cancel' was clicked.

A minimal example:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    (sink, self.dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, 'Output', context,
                                                list_of_fields,
                                                QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
                                                CRS)

    for result in results:
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            break

        # Do smth smart

        sink.addFeature(result)

    return {'Output': self.dest_id}
```

However, no layer is added to the map when 'Cancel' is hit mid-way through processing.

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, I'd have expected that `if feedback.isCanceled(): break` would yield `return {'Output': self.dest_id}`, i.e. the output layer with the added features until `feedback.isCanceled()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Asked the same question on the QGIS dev mailing list and according to @nyalldawson this is intended behavior, so as not to receive misleading partial results.